# Как можно вытащить id товара из полученной строки?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, функции, woocommerce

Есть магазин на wordpress+woocommerce, и в произвольные поля продукта можно добавить подарок, к которому можно обратиться с помощью мета данных таким способом:

```
global $product;
$meta_values = get_post_meta($product->post->ID);
if(!$meta_values['wfg_single_gift_enabled']) {
            $gift_id = $meta_values["_wfg_single_gift_products"];
            echo $gift_id[0];
        }
```

На выходе получаем строчку в таком виде: `a:1:{i:0;s:4:"6090";}`
из которой я хочу вытащить`ID=6090` товара, чтобы можно было с ним взаимодействовать. Как это правильно сделать? большая вероятность, что наполнение  строки и будет отличаться для разных случаев, но `id` будет всегда присутствовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это , так называемая, сериализованная строка

```
print_r(unserialize('a:1:{i:0;s:4:"6090";}'));
```

результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6090
)
```